# Defining a macro for iterate

Tags: loops, macros, common-lisp

I wanted to define a new clause for the [iterate](https://common-lisp.net/project/iterate/) macro. Something similar to Python's [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) where you have a `start, stop, step`. Here's a first try:

```lisp
(defmacro-clause (for var start start stop stop step step)
  (if (minusp step)
      `(for ,var from ,start downto ,stop by (- ,step))
      `(for ,var from ,start to     ,stop by ,step)))
```

It deals with increasing and decreasing ranges using the `to` and `downto` keywords of iterate. (Note that, unlike Python, these include the `stop` value.)

This works as desired for

```lisp
(iter (for x start 5 stop 3 step -1)
      (collect x))

;; => (5 4 3)

(iter (for x start 2 stop 5 step 1)
      (collect x))

;; => (3,4,5)
```

However it fails for anything like

```lisp
(let ((a 9)
      (b 3)
      (c -1))
  (iter (for x start a stop b step c)
        (collect x)))
```

Is it a quirk of `iterate` that it requires explicit numbers in these places? It has no problem with things like

```lisp
(iter (for x below (+ 3 3) by (+ 1 1))
      (collect x))
```

Concretely my question is, how can I define a new `iterate` clause that accepts variables which are bound to numbers in these places?

Comment: Your problem is that you use `step` at macro expansion time.  That will not work at all if it is not a number literal, and not as intended otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Svante but it's not clear to me what you mean. Why do you think that step needs to be a number literal and not an expression? Or, in other words, what aspect of the macro expansion makes that inadmissible?

Comment: You are evaluating the sign of the step at macro expansion time.  The actually compiled code then has only one of the epansions (either that for positive or negative steps).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to decide things at macro-expansion time which can't be known then, such as the sign of a variable.  In particular you can't write a macro which expands into (part of) another macro depending on anything which is only known at run time, or you can, but that necessarily means you have to call the moral equivalent of `eval` at run-time, and ... don't do that.

Instead you have to make the decision about which way to count at run-time.  This means you can't use any of the `(for var from ...)` or related clauses because there don't seem to be any which are agnostic about direction (why `(for i from 1 to -5 by -1)` doesn't work is beyond me but ... well).

So whatever clause you end up with needs to expand into a `(for var next ...)` clause, I think.

Here is an attempt at such.  Disclaimer: not tested very much, I don't use iterate, may explode on contact, poisonous to fish.

```
(defmacro-driver (for v in-range a to b &optional by s)
  (let ((firstp (make-symbol "FIRSTP"))
        (value (make-symbol "VALUE"))
        (limit (make-symbol "LIMIT"))
        (step (make-symbol "STEP")))
    `(progn
       (with ,firstp = t)
       (with ,value = (let ((v ,a))
                        (unless (numberp v)
                          (warn "doomed"))
                        (when (null v)
                          (warn "extremely doomed"))
                        v))
       (with ,limit = (let ((v ,b))
                        (unless (numberp v)
                          (warn "also doomed"))
                        v))
       (with ,step = (let ((v (or ,s (signum (- ,limit ,value)))))
                       (when (not (numberp v))
                         (warn "doomed again"))
                       (when (zerop v)
                         (warn "zero step"))
                       (when (not (= (signum v) (signum (- ,limit ,value))))
                         (warn "likely doomed"))
                       v))
       (,(if generate 'generate 'for)
        ,v
        next (if ,firstp
                 (progn
                   (setf ,firstp nil)
                   ,value)
               (progn
                 (incf ,value ,step)
                 (when (if (> ,step 0)
                           (>= ,value ,limit)
                         (<= ,value ,limit))
                   (terminate))
                 ,value))))))
```

And now

```
> (iter (for i in-range 1 to 5 by 2)
    (print i))

1 
3
nil

> (iter (for i in-range 1 to -1)
    (print i))

1
0
nil

> (iter (for i in-range 1 to 5 by -2)
    (when (< i -20)
      (terminate)))
Warning: likely doomed
nil
```

Obviously some of the checks could be better.